# SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing, beautifulsoup, pip

I am getting a Syntax Error EOL on the print line. I tried adding more commas but it wont work.

```
def getAuthorized(url, username, password):

r = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password))

    if str(r.status_code) != '401':
        print "\n[!] Username: " + username + " Password: " + password + " 
         Code: " + str(r.status_code) +  "\n"
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: You can't break a line in the middle of a (single-quoted) string literal. Break the line after the `+` or not at all.

Comment: @RithinChalumuri Note the `print` statement; this is Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

Adding commas will not work. The Problem Here is that:

```
def getAuthorized(url, username, password):

r = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password))

    if str(r.status_code) != '401':
        print "\n[!] Username: " + username + " Password: " + password + " 
         Code: " + str(r.status_code) +  "\n"
```

You can split the print into two lines , but I don’t suggest you to. The print line should be:

```
print "\n[!] Username: " + username + " Password: " + password + " Code: " + str(r.status_code) +  "\n"
```

So the final code should be:

```
def getAuthorized(url, username, password):

r = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password))

    if str(r.status_code) != '401':
        print "\n[!] Username: " + username + " Password: " + password + " Code: " + str(r.status_code) +  "\n"
```

Comment: *You cannot split the print into two lines* No true, you can split any statement into multiple lines using backslashes as continuation character.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `"…Code: "` — Python doesn't allow to make a single-quoted string multiline; only triple-quoted strings can be multiline. To fix:

```
print "\n[!] Username: " + username + " Password: " + password + \
      " \n Code: " + str(r.status_code) +  "\n"
```

Please note a backslash at the end of the first line: it's required to continue the statement `print` on the next line.